# Jquery which creates a div element with Image on it. Cannot write Text on it - JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am creating div elements on the click function using Jquery. Also with the properties of draggable and resizable. The div gets generated as expected with background image.

I am also trying to append text on it with `$("#box").html("Test")` .But this results into the box not getting **resizable** or **draggable** .

Here is my CSS :

```
<style>
#mover {
        border: 2px solid;
        padding: 10px 40px;
        width: 300px;
        /*resize: both;*/
        /*overflow: auto;*/
    }

    .comp1 {
        border: 2px solid;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("Images/florist.png");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .comp2 {
        border: 2px solid;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url("Images/caterer.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border-radius:50%;
    }

</style>
```

Script :

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#AddComp").click(function () {
                    $("#box").append("<div class='comp1'></div>");
                    $("#box").html("TEst");
                    $("#box .comp1").resizable({ containment: "#box" });
                    $("#box .comp1").draggable({ containment: "#box" });
                });

                $("#circle").click(function () {
                    $("#box").append("<div class='comp2'></div>");
                    $("#box .comp2").resizable({ containment: "#box" });
                    $("#box .comp2").draggable({ containment: "#box" });
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML :

```
 <a id="AddComp">Square</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="circle">Circle</a>

    <div id="box" style="border:double;min-height:700px;min-width:900px">


    </div>
```

P.S. : I want to append text on the created div with jquery or css .

Comment: `.html("TEst")` overwrites the whole content of `#box` so the `.comp1` div is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when this statement is executed

```
$("#box").html("Test");
```

you are destroying the `.comp1` element you previously created into your `#box` element (same issue for `.comp2` element). Probably you may want instead

```
$("#box .comp1").text("Test");
```

As a side note, cache your selectors, especially if you need to use them several times, or chain the methods so to avoid useless (expensive) calls to the `jQuery` function

Comment: Thanks so much that worked and how can i `style` the text which i have added later...?

Comment: using css, e.g.  `#box [class^="comp"] { color: ... ; }`

Comment: and should i include this code in the css or in the script ..??

Comment: that is css, so place it in your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You aren't making the box resizable or draggable. You're doing that to some of its descendants (`.comp1` and `.comp2` elements).

When you `$("#box").html("Test")`, you are deleting those elements and replacing them with a text node.

You need to do one of:

- modify the content of those elements instead of the content of the whole box
- `append()` the new content so it doesn't remove the old controls
- put new elements in the box instead of a simple string of text, select the new elements, then make them resizable and draggable

Answer (score 0):

you must add the text to `.comp1`

```
 $("#box .comp1").html("Test")
```